# Инициализация значимых типов в C#

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Читаю книгу, написанную Дж. Рихтером, CLR via C#. К сожалению, в самом начале у меня возникают вопросы. Надеюсь, вы поможете мне разобраться.

Джеффри пишет, что различие между значимыми и ссылочными типами заключается в том, что значимые типы хранятся в стеке потока, в то время как ссылочные типы хранятся по принципу: объект типа лежит в управляемой куче, а ссылка на этот объект находится в стеке. Далее он говорит, что ссылка на объект ссылочного типа возвращается оператором 'new'. А для значимых типов возвращать ссылку не нужно, поэтому можно не писать оператор 'new'.

Дж. Рихтер приводит пример:

```
struct SomeVal { public Int32 x; } // здесь он объявляет структуру
SomeVal v1 = new SomeVal();
```

Потом он добавляет, что строку выше можно записать иначе:

```
SomeVal v1;
```

Дословно:

> Здесь тоже создается IL-код, который помещает экземпляр SomeVal в стек
>   потока **и обнуляет все его поля.**

Подскажите, правда ли это? Ведь мы же не можем обратиться к какому-нибудь полю структуры до тех пор, пока не выполним его инициализацию. А по словам Джеффри выходит, что ничего инициализировать не нужно, ведь все поля сами обнуляются.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это правда. Вся выделенная память просто инициализируется нулями.

> Ведь мы же не можем обратиться к какому-нибудь полю структуры до тех пор, пока не выполним его инициализацию.

Это проверка C# компилятора, CLR же не накладывает таких ограничений. Книга Рихтера -- она же в первую очередь о CLR, поэтому он не врет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но я теперь не понимаю, зачем разработчики компилятора ввели такое ограничение? Они до такой степени за "безопасность написанного кода" ?

Comment: @radzko да. Вот хороший ответ от Эрика Липперта: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931226/are-c-sharp-uninitalized-variables-dangerous/8933935#8933935. Вкратце: "Причина в том, что использование неинициализированной переменной вероятнее всего является ошибкой."

Comment: @UladzislauRadzko можете пометить ответ как верный (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: Да, конечно. Как-то не обратил внимание. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @UladzislauRadzko не за что.